# Detect property changes on elements via their attributes - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I was wondering if it was possible to detect property changes made to elements via their attributes.

For example, we can add inheritable properties and methods to elements by working with the `HTMLElement.prototype` object and its inherited prototypes e.g.:

```
// Add our global property
HTMLElement.prototype.sandwich = 'double-decker variety';

// Get the <body> element
let body = document.body;
body.sandwich // => 'double-decker variety'
```

So, is there a way to extend this to element attributes?

Or should I be working on the `Attr.prototype` object instead?

```
// Add our global property
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'burger', {
    ...,
    set: function changeBurger(newValue) {
        // Our response
        console.log(`Response: You changed our '${oldValue}' burger to a '${newValue}'`)
    }
});

// Get the <body> element
let body = document.body;

// Response: You changed our 'king-sized' burger to a 'family pack'
body.burger = 'family pack';

// Response: You changed our 'family pack' burger to a 'kids delight'
body.setAttribute('burger', 'kids delight');
```

The example above should also be applicable to elements that are not in the DOM or current document i.e.: Objects intialized from the `HTMLElement` constructor.

Sorry if the question seems a bit vague and I do hope the examples I've given out are able to clarify the question topic.

Thanks to anyone willing to take the time to answer.

Comment: Maybe using proxies could work.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work, the response callback is to be invoked whenever the attribute or property `burger` is changed from not only the `<body>` element, but all objects from the `HTMLElement` constructor.

And I think using a `Proxy` would only detect changes for one DOM element at a time.

Answer (score 3):

**The right way** to extend HTMLElement is using [CustomElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements),
There is a lifecycle callback named `attributeChangedCallback`.

Then, when setting an attribute using objectName.setAttribute('attrName','attrValue')
this function is invoked.

**You can also use** [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) with `config={attributes:true}` (be careful using it, a wrong implementation will severely damage performance).

**Another way** of achieving this, is to write a function which read all attribute and convert them to setter/getters... something like this

```js
    class WatchableObject{
            constructor(){
                this.handler = ()=>{};
            }
            watch(handler){
                if(!this.beingWatched()) {
                    delete this.handler;

                    let properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
                    properties.forEach((prop) => {
                        if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                            Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                                set: (newValue) => {
                                    let oldValue = this["_" + prop];
                                    this["_" + prop] = newValue;
                                    this.handler.call(this,oldValue,newValue);
                                },
                                get: () => {
                                    return this["_" + prop];
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                this.handler = handler;
            }
            unwatch(){
                this.watch(()=>{});
            }
            beingWatched(){
                return (this.handler.toString() != "()=>{}");
            }
    }

    let a = new WatchableObject();
    a.b = "hello";
    a.c = "daniel";
    a.watch(()=>{alert("a change has been made.")});
    a.b = "bye";
    a.unwatch();
    a.b = "hello again";
```

Comment: Is this by any chance possible with the other browsers.
Because the way I see it, **Mozilla Firefox** and **Microsoft Edge** do not support the CustomElements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/customElements) API yet.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately it is still partially supported... I Will check for other methods as well

Comment: I added two more methods

Comment: Thanks for the support, really. After re-thinking the question, I ended up just editing the `Element.prototype.setAttribute` method and its variants (which is kinda cheaty, but for now it works).

Comment: You welcome :) be advised - I think changing the Element.prototype.setAttribute will not react to changes made by the browser, for example - if you wish to know the width of a div (which will change according to the window size), or the parentElement of some node after moving it - I think they will not trigger your function. good luck friend